# How to plot map with auto name annotation?

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I tried to plot a map like this:
[image: map]

It's easy to plot the background, is it possible to add the names automatically?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import numpy as np
ax = plt.subplot(projection=ccrs.NorthPolarStereo())
ax.set_extent([0, 360, 50, 90], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.stock_img()
ax.coastlines()

# Compute a circle in axes coordinates, which we can use as a boundary
# for the map. We can pan/zoom as much as we like - the boundary will be
# permanently circular.
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
center, radius = [0.5, 0.5], 0.5
verts = np.vstack([np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]).T
circle = mpath.Path(verts * radius + center)

ax.set_boundary(circle, transform=ax.transAxes)
```

[image: map2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no automatic map annotation plotting with cartopy. But it is possible to do so with some programming and data. Proper locations and orientations of the anno-texts will be needed. Here is the code that demonstrates the process.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[8, 8])
ax = plt.subplot(projection=ccrs.NorthPolarStereo())
#ax.set_extent([0, 360, 50, 90], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent([-180, 180, 50, 90], ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.stock_img()
ax.coastlines()

def map_annotation(lonlat_list, rotate_deg, anno_text):
    l2 = np.array(lonlat_list)
    # Rotate angle
    angle = rotate_deg
    trans_angle = plt.gca().transData.transform_angles(np.array((angle,)),
                                                       l2.reshape((1, 2)))[0]
    plt.text(l2[0], l2[1] , anno_text,
             rotation=trans_angle, rotation_mode='anchor',
             transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

# Annotate some areas/features for demonstratioin
map_annotation((0, 60), 90, 'Prime  meridian')
map_annotation((-42, 65.5), 45, '    Greenland')
map_annotation((-102, 60), 45, 'C a n a d a')
map_annotation((38, 55), 70, 'R   u   s   s   i   a')

theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
center, radius = [0.5, 0.5], 0.5
verts = np.vstack([np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]).T
circle = mpath.Path(verts * radius + center)

ax.set_boundary(circle, transform=ax.transAxes)

plt.show()
```

The output:-

[image: annotextmap]